# How to enable React component re-rendering both before and after async call?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, render

I have a component responsible for reading and displaying an image and I want to display a waiting spinner while the image is being loaded. I am trying to achieve this through component's state:

```
function loadAndCacheImage(imagePath) {
  // Async image loader
};

function displayImage(image) {
  // Display image
};

class Viewer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      imagePath: undefined
    }
  };

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.imagePath!==undefined && this.state.imagePath===undefined) {
      this.setState({loading: true});
    }
  };

  render() {
    const container = (
      <Row>
        <Viewport id={this.props.imageId} />
      </Row>
    );
    return (
        <Spin spinning={this.state.loading} size={'large'} >{container}</Spin>
    );
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      loadAndCacheImage(this.props.imagePath).then((image) => {
        displayImage(image);
        this.setState({loading: false, imagePath: this.props.imagePath});
      });

    }
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is that when the component receives props, it updates the state, but doesn't re-render the component. It waits for the end of the async image loader to actually update the component: the loading spinner flickers once as loading state is set to true and then immediately to false.

Any suggestion on how to solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I''m missing some information. With the code you provided the component should render once and that's it. Is there any more code affecting the state?

Comment: Ah got it now. You set the imagePath from the outside and that triggers the rerendering.

Comment: The component renders twice, here is the dataflow: the default loading state is `false`. Then the component evaluates if an image path is provided in `componentWillReceiveProps`, setting the loading state to `true`. When component is updated and if it is in loading state, it reads and displays the image and sets the loading state back to `false`. So I pretend to have two renderings: one showing empty container with loading spinner and other showing the loaded image, with loading spinner hidden.

Comment: Ok so the component receives props, sets the state to true and renders (spinning). After the rendering componentDidUpdate is called. The state is true so loadAnCacheImage is called. But the spinner is not removed, e. g. the state is not set back to false, right?

Comment: This is what happens: the component receives props, sets the state to true, calls componentDidUpdate, **but does not render the spinner**. The state is still evaluated to true and calls loadAnCacheImage. The image is displayed and the then the spinner is rendered for an instant and then disappears again, as if the flow of execution was: load image -> display image -> set state to true -> set state to false

Comment: I'd really like to help you, but I think I need to see this with my own eyes. Maybe by screen sharing. I believe it's an asynchronous issue that is caused by the two functions you skipped. If you'd like to share screen just get in touch with me by e-mail (stackoverflow profile) and I will answer the conclusion afterwards so that everybody else can profit from this.

Comment: Thank you for your availability. Indeed the problem is caused by ffi module that calls a native library inside the `loadAndCacheImage` function. I am still trying to figure out why this prevents the component from rendering.

Comment: ok thanks for your update

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but it looks like you need to use some other lifecycle methods

```
class Viewer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      imagePath: undefined
    }
  };


    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ loading: true },
         loadAndCacheImage(this.props.imagePath).then((image) => {
           displayImage(image);
           this.setState({
             loading: false,
              imagePath: this.props.imagePath 
            });
          });
);

      }


  render() {
    const container = (
      <Row>
        <Viewport id={this.props.imageId} />
      </Row>
    );
    return (
        <Spin spinning={this.state.loading} size={'large'} >{container}</Spin>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I cannot use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method since I need to have a mounted component and only then assign an image path upon user interaction.

Comment: If you need to do it based on user interaction (say click of a button), try this

```<Button onClick={this.loadImage} />``` & loadImage should do what is written in ```componentDidMount```. (set loading: true, and after loading, will set loading: false), & then you'll see the image.